# Difference between 笛 and 龠

Tags: meaning, kanji

both of these mean 'flute.' Is there any difference other than 龠 being a radical?

Comment: They are not really things you can compare. 龠 is simply uncommon.

Answer (score 3):

笛 is a very common kanji that broadly refers to flutes or whistles all over the world.

龠 seems to be a very rare kanji that referred to a certain type of ancient Chinese [pan flute](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pan_flute) made of bamboo. It does not refer to flutes in general. Most Japanese people do not even know this kanji or the musical instrument. The kanji that contain this radical are all very rare, and you can practically forget this radical/kanji if you are a beginner leaner of Japanese.